# Pass data and file array using knockout, ajax and web api

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I've knockout web page with lots of data and place for uploading an array of images. 
In the end, there's a button with send method and I want to send my all data and images to Wep Api controller. 
I've been struggling to pass those images, whatever I try it sends an empty array. The page doesn't contains a form, so I cannot try sending new FormData object too.

Button:

```
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: fogBugzForm.send">Submit</button>
```

Send method:

```
     this.send = () => {
            var data = {
                screenshots: this.fogBugzData().screenshots(), // knockoutObservableArray<string>
                otherStringData: this.fogBugzData().otherStringData()
            };

            if (this.fogBugzData.isValid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ko.toJSON(data),
                    url: "api/FogBuzReporter/ReportBug",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                });
```

Web API controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ReportBug([FromBody] FogBuzModel bug)
    {
        ...
    }


    public class FogBuzModel
    {
       public string[] screenshots { get; set; }
       public string otherStringData {get;set;}
    }
```

1. If I log file from this array in console it's full of information about this image
2. If I log ko.toJSON(data) this array is empty

Any help would be great :)

Comment: well `ko.toJSON(data)` cannot be empty if your doing right . check this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25266/ . Try giving us a fiddle sample which explains your issue .

Comment: It happend to be my stupid mistake. Screenshots shouldn't be an array of string but of File. To send both data from form and files I've create new FormData and passed it all. Thank You for You help !

Comment: humm ! glad i can help a bit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.data = [
         { Name: "Nokia Lumia", price: 10000, Image: "Images/Phones/lumia.jpg" },
         { Name: "Xiaomi MI3", price: 9999.99, Image: "Images/Phones/mi3.jpg" },
         { Name: "Apple Iphone", price: 50000, Image: "Images/Phones/iphone.jpg" },
         { Name: "HTC One", price: 40000, Image: "Images/Phones/htc.jpg" },
         { Name: "OnePlus One", price: 22990, Image: "Images/Phones/oneplus.jpg" },
         { Name: "Sony Xperia", price: 30000, Image: "Images/Phones/xperia.jpg" },
         { Name: "Galaxy Note4", price: 48000, Image: "Images/Phones/note.jpg" }
           ];

  $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("WriteData","Home")",
                     type: "post",
                     data: JSON.stringify(self.data[0]),
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     success: function (question) {
                         bootbox.alert("Product saved successfully");
                     },
                     error: function () {
                         alert("Something went wrong");


                     }
        });
```

Hi, I don't see any issue in what you wrote in your question but check once again.
I am using **this piece of code to send some data to method "WriteData"** in Home controller(using MVC here).

**WriteData** looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public string WriteData(ShopItems item)
    {
        Product ob = new Product();
        bool result=ob.Write(item);
        if (result)
            return "true";
        else return "false";
    }
```

and ShopItems:

```
public class ShopItems
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public double price { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

}
```

This whole code is working perfect. Try once and please let me know.

Comment: It works perfect, I've made different mistake (in my first comment). Thank You for Your time.